# ¿Por que no sale del if si el usuario al registrarse cumple con los criterios de validacion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, formularios

Estoy haciendo la logica de un formulario de registro, y necesito validar los campos de las contraseñas pero resulta que cuando escribo la contraseña y su confirmacion correctamente, no continua ejecutando la siguiente linea de codigo y me envia el ultimo alert diciendo que las contraseñas no coinciden. Alguien podria decirme por que?

```
    if ($("#txtPassword").length < 8) {
        alert('Your password must be at least 8 characters long');
        return;

    } else if  ($("#txtPassword") != $("#confPasword")) {
        alert("The password does not match");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Haz un alert de las dos variables a ver si realmente coinciden o no.

Comment: Es un input el #txtPassword?

Comment: `$("#txtPassword")` no es la contraseña, es el element si es un input, use `$("#txtPassword").val()` para obtener la contraseña

Answer (score 1):

Como lo expreso @skara9 `$(...)` es un objeto JQuery que envuelve al elemento input, para obtener el `value` debes usar le método `$(...).val()`

> Vea la documentación: https://api.jquery.com/val/

Este pequeño ejemplo quizás le ilustre un poco:

```js
console.log('1. typeof $("#field").val() : ', typeof $("#field").val());
console.log('2. $("#field").val()        : ', $("#field").val());
console.log('3. typeof $("#field")       : ', typeof $("#field"));
console.log('4. $("#field")              : ', $("#field"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="field" value="">
```

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias por que ademas de ese error, con tu ayuda descubri que tenia mal escrito el campo del password. Era confPassword y lo tenia una S. Mil gracias por ayudarme!!!